# Retrieving data by other field than id in has many relations

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a has many relation between models: post and category in laravel application. I've defined these relations as:

```
public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('artSite\category');
}

public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('artSite\post');
}
```

Now I'm trying retrieve posts belonging to the particular category which are derived in http request:

```
Route::get('posts/categories/{categoryName}','postsViewController@showPostGivenCategory')
```

Below I show my controller function (it does work fine!):

```
 public function showPostGivenCategory($categoryName) {

     $category = category::where('category_name','=',$categoryName)-first();
     $posts = category::find($category->id)->posts;
     return view('pages.homePage')->with('categories',$categories)with('posts',$posts);

 }
```

In this solution I'm creating 2 queries. Is any possible way to create 1 query to retrieve posts of particular category in has many relation?

Something like that doesn't work:

```
$posts = category::where('category_name','=',$categoryName)->posts;
```

Could someone help me with this problem? I would be very grateful, greetings.

Comment: Why dont you just pass the $category->id on the request instead of the name?  Then you can just pass the id directly without searching for the actual category.  You could also decide to use findOrFail() to ensure you retrieve categories that exists or handle the exception.  Or you could also use findMany([]) which would allow you to retrieve more than one category at the same time.  But first I would try to just pass the id instead of the name of the category.  How are the categories being picked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get rid of the second line :

```
 $posts = Category::find($category->id)->posts;
```

So You can say :

```
$posts = Category::where('category_name','=',$categoryName)->first()->posts;
```